# AndEngine Box2D Body GetContactList

Tags: java, android, box2d, andengine

Ive been trying to learn the Physics Box2D Extension for AndEngine and I have been reading http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082975

Under "9.3 Accessing Contacts" it says

> You can also iterate over all the contacts on a body

My understanding is that I should be able to do

```
myBody().GetContactList()
```

But I cant seem to find it. Am I missing something here? should I be able to do this?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

ok, I've looked in Body.java for the Box2DExtension and found

```
// ArrayList<ContactEdge> getContactList()
// {
// return contacts;
// }
```

commented out, does anybody know why. I will still have a look but if anybody could find the answer quicker than me it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Thought id share what I found: After more googling I found [this](http://www.andengine.org/forums/features/why-is-body-getcontactlist-deactivated-t3851.html) where it is explained that the Box2d extension is pulled from [libgdx](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx) and the file that is supposed to have .GetContactList() is [Body.java](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Body.java) line 772 which has been commented out for a while. I don't know why it hasn't been implemented but at least I know why I'm not able to call it.